# Etcher appimage not working in Ubuntu20.04

Tags: 20.04, appimage

Doubling clicking the appimage did not work so I tried the following commands

```
chmod +x .appimage
sudo ./.appimage
```

but it gives me the error

```
dlopen(): error loading libfuse.so.2

AppImages require FUSE to run. 
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage 
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option. 
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE 
for more information
```

but Fuse is installed in my system.

```
apt-cache policy libfuse2
libfuse2:
  Installed: 2.9.9-3
  Candidate: 2.9.9-3
  Version table:
 *** 2.9.9-3 500
        500 http://mirror.xeonbd.com/ubuntu-archive focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Are you sure that FUSE is installed in your system?  What's the output of `apt-cache policy libfuse2`?

Comment: @ThomasWard <pre>libfuse2:
  Installed: 2.9.9-3
  Candidate: 2.9.9-3
  Version table:
 *** 2.9.9-3 500
        500 http://mirror.xeonbd.com/ubuntu-archive focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
</pre>

Comment: OK so it is installed.   I would surmise that the AppImage is broken, and you should contact the creator and file a bug there.  It's possible this is an issue in the AppImage itself.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I just opened a new issue on their github repo. @ThomasWard

Comment: Did you download the correct architecture of the Appimage: Linux x64 (64-bit) / Linux x86 (32-bit)?

Comment: In https://www.balena.io/etcher/  there is not 64-bit for Linux. there's only 32-bit appimage for LInux @Bodo

Comment: I just checked the download pull-down menu. It shows "Etcher for Linux x64 (64-bit) (AppImage)" and "Etcher for Linux x86 (32-bit) (AppImage)". See also this old problem report https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/issues/1490  You could try `strace -e trace=file ./.appimage` to see where it wants to find `libfuse.so.2`. You could also try the `.deb` packages from https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/releases

Comment: I read the 64-bit download button in the front page as only Download button. so i clicked the pull-down icon and only saw the 32-bit version. thanx for pointing that out :D @Bodo

Comment: You should have written in your question what Appimage file you downloaded as you did in the GitHub issue. This would have made it clear that the 32-bit Appimage does not match the 64-bit library.

Comment: I added an answer, mainly for other users that may have a similar problem. I also wrote a suggestion to improve the message as an issue for the AppImage project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [corresponding issue](https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/issues/3574) the downloaded Appimage file is a 32-bit version

> ```
> balenaEtcher-1.5.121-ia32
> ```

while the installed library is 64-bit

> ```
> apt-cache policy libfuse2
> ...
>         500 http://mirror.xeonbd.com/ubuntu-archive focal/main amd64 Packages
> ```

Unfortunately the error message from the Appimage code is insufficient:

> ```
> dlopen(): error loading libfuse.so.2
>
> AppImages require FUSE to run.
> ...
> ```

It doesn't tell what version of the library the `dlopen()` call searched for or where it searched for the library. This is a bit confusing when you see that the library `libfuse.so.2` is installed on your system, contrary to the error message.

Running the Appimage with `strace` might show that it searches for the library in directories for 32-bit libraries.

So in case of this error you should check if the architecture of the Appimage file matches your system's architecture.

Comment: `strace` solved it for me, I noticed it was looking for the 32bit version.

Answer (score 5):

According to [arduino](https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/8327482047772-If-you-get-an-dlopen-error-loading-libfuse-so-2-error) installing the `libfuse2` package could resolve the issue.  I have Ubuntu 22.04 and it worked fine for me :

```
sudo apt-get -y install libfuse2
```